# JavaScript string comparison always returns true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing my first project using AngularJS and now i've run into a JavaScript problem that just can't understand. Perhaps this is trivial to someone more experienced in JS, if so i hope you guys can help me :)

I've doing this string comparison in function, that receives an id passed as a parameter from a view, which it then compares to id of objects kept in the service:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.Sessions.length; i++) {

        if (this.Sessions[i].sessionId === sessionId) {

            for (var j = 0; j < this.Sessions[i].Instances.length; j++) {
                if (this.Sessions[i].Instances[j].instanceId === instanceId);
                {
                    console.log("InstanceId's: " + this.workoutSessions[i].Instances[j].instanceId + " " + instanceId);

                    //Do stuff and return.

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run the method all the instanceId's of all the instances will evaluate to true.. Why??? As far as i know i'm just comparing strings, but i guess not. The outer comparison works as it should, which makes it even stranger to me.

Output in console, showing that they evaluate to true no matter the value of the strings.

InstanceId's: l0h34qzzgdlpu8fr 42p9smh9kxdsfw29

InstanceId's: 42p9smh9kxdsfw29 42p9smh9kxdsfw29

Really what i want to do is stop the function as soon as i've found the correct instance, but if i put in a return statement inside the IF-block my compiler tells me the j++ statement is unreachable, indicating no matter what the expression is going to be true, and... that is just beyond me.

How the parameter is passed from the view:

```
    <div ng-repeat="instance in session.Instances">

    //Some form controls here...

    <div style="float: right;">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addOne(session.sessionId, instance.instanceId)"> + 1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Remove</button>    
    </div>

</div>
```

Can anybody help??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks like `if(...); { }` . That `;` is not needed...

Comment: can you setup a plunker... cant play around with the provided code to find out the issue...

Comment: yep @DCoder is right, doing this: "if (this.Sessions[i].Instances[j].instanceId === instanceId);" is the same as doing this: "if (this.Sessions[i].Instances[j].instanceId === instanceId){}"

Comment: For f***s sake... You're completely right, i was terminating the if block with the semi-colon... I've been staring at this for a day and a half... Thank you so much! Especially, for not telling how ignorant this is of me ;)

Comment: Look into getting a better IDE, such as [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). It will highlight a lot of common mistakes/oversights like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (this.Sessions[i].Instances[j].instanceId === instanceId);
```

the colon at the end seems to be the culprit...

Answer (score 0):

delete the semicolon in the if clause.

Your Code will be same as

```
 if (this.Sessions[i].Instances[j].instanceId === instanceId)
 {
      ;
 }

 {
      console.log("InstanceId's: " + this.workoutSessions[i].Instances[j].instanceId + " " + instanceId);
      //Do stuff and return.
 }
```